# Custom kendo grid toolbar button

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid, in which I added a custom button in the toolbar. I have mapped a on click function to that button.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="clearfix">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>()
    .Name("successfullData")
    .ToolBar(e =>
    {
    e.Custom().Text("Save").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "customSaveButton", @class = "floatRight" });
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Input(true).Numeric(false))
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Groupable()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
    columns.Bound(c => c.OPERATOR_OBJECTID).Title("ID").Hidden();
    columns.Bound(c => c.SETTLEMENT_CODE).Title("settlement code").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(c => c.TECHNOLOGY_CODE).Title("tech code").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(c => c.UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE).Title("upload").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(c => c.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_CODE).Title("download").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(c => c.DATA_CATEGORY_QOS_CODE).Title("data category").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(c => c.SHAPE).Title("shape").Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(c => c.messageOut).Title("message").Width("100px");
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Upload_Read", "Upload").Data("sendAdditional"))
    )
    )

  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function sendAdditional() {
    var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model?.TableNotificationModel))');

    return {
      model: data
    }
  }

  $("#successfullData").on("click", "#customSaveButton", function () {
    var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model?.TableNotificationModel))');


    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveFile", "Upload")',
      data: {
        model: model,
        saveType: saveType
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

I added a function which send the model via an ajax call to my controller where I am returning a view.
The problem is, the custom save button adds a `#` in the URL and I think it's because of that I cannot return the view of my action in the controller.

```
public ActionResult SaveFile(List<TableNotificationModel> model)
{
  //code shortened for brevity
  ViewBag.Message = String.Format(cmdMessage);
  return View(tModel);
}
```

I am kind of stuck, I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: _the custom save button adds a `#` in the URL_ - can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your javascript function is identifying your button event by the ID: "customSaveButton".

For example:

```
 $('#customSaveButton').on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/YourContreoller/SaveFile',
        type: 'POST',   
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#dataThatYouWantToSend').serialize(),
        success: function (sucess) {
            console.log("Success");
            document.location.href = '/'
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(textStatus);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I added additional info in the original post but yes. I get the `on-click` event of the button by it's id.

Comment: Ok cool, Try to put [HttpPost] on your post method (SaveFile). Btw test putting your url: directly with the dataType.